# Azure SignalR Service is throwing 503 error when web service tries to connect

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, signalr

We have one Blazor server app and one SignalR Hub both hosted on Azure web services which reference a SignalR Service they both are return returning a 502 when 101 was expected.

We ran out of messages in the free tier, which I'm assuming is part of the issue, So I changed to paid and still getting an error.

We somehow burned through 17k messages in a couple minutes and have no idea where they came from.  The desktop client that uses the SignalR Hub was not running, which means it would have had to be from the Blazor server. Are there any suggested ways to further troubleshoot, possibly see what IP addresses the messages are coming from and going to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may refer to this [tutorial on resource logs for Azure SignalR Service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-signalr/signalr-howto-diagnostic-logs) are, how to set them up, and how to troubleshoot with them.

To add to this for the SignalR resource in a free tier instance has a message limit of 20000 per day.

Please check below document on how messages are counted in SignalR service:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-signalr/signalr-concept-messages-and-connections

If large messages split into smaller ones and counted as multiple messages, In this case connections gets throttled.

If the message count is expected, then the only solution is to scale the instance to Standard tier which doesn’t have a hard message count limit.

Comment: Thanks for the info. While I was hoping for a little more explicit direction, as I have seen all of those articles before, we did find out the issue.  We picked Log Analytics mentioned in the first article and saw that all our traffic is due to our blazor server instance. This was only from a couple client connections.  I feel this should be better documented for Blazor. Looks like we might have to switch to WASM and knowing this before hand would have been helpful.